# K Means Algorithm in MATLAB - Explain the Cluster Label Assignment Step

Tags: matlab, k-means

I have a Matlab code from my class in which the professor does the step of assigning each data point to the nearest cluster using this code where c is the centroids matrix and x is the data matrix.

```
  % norm squared of the centroids; 
  c2 = sum(c.^2, 1);  

  % For each data point x, computer min_j  -2 * x' * c_j + c_j^2;
  % Note that here is implemented as max, so the difference is negated.
  tmpdiff = bsxfun(@minus, 2*x'*c, c2); 
  [val, labels] = max(tmpdiff, [], 2);
```

I am not sure how this is equivalent to the algorithm definition of this step in which the cluster assignment is done through

```
% For every centroid j and for every data point x_i
labels(i) = `argmin||x_i - c_j||^2`
```

Can anyone please explain to me how this works, essentially how computing

```
min_j  -2 * x' * c_j + c_j^2
```

is equivalent to

```
 argmin||x_i - c_j||^2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we have a triangle such that the length of its sides is `a, b, c`, then
we know that (from the [law of cosines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_cosines))

```
a^2=c^2+b^2-2bc*cos(alpha)
```

where `alpha` is the angle between the side with size `b` and the size with size `c`.

Now, consider the triangle made of the three vertices `x`, `c_j` and `O` (the origin of `R^n`). Writing `theta` the angle between `x` and `c`, we have

```
 argmin_j||x-c_j||^2
 =argmin_j (||x||^2+||c_j||^2 - 2*||x||* ||c_j|| * cos(theta)  )
```

which is equal to

```
 argmin_j(||x||^2 + ||c||^2 - 2x^t c_j)
```

Now, remember that `x` is constant in this minimization, so the last equation is just equal to

```
argmin_j(||c_j||^2 - 2 x^t c_j)
```

which is the equation you minimize in your code.

Comment: Very good. This is correct. +1.  If I can recommend something, use something like http://quicklatex.com to render your equations into actual images.  It'll drive the quality of your answer much farther.

Comment: Thank you for you suggestion, I'll do this as soon as I can. I really wish we could use Latex on stackoverflow, just like on the math or even robotics stackexchange sites...

Comment: I agree.  Very annoying.  There has been a subject of debate whether to support LaTeX on Stack Overflow, but they won't due to the amount of overhead... doesn't make sense as a variety of other SE websites support it (Math, Signal Processing, Electrical Engineering, Physics, etc.).

Comment: I wouldn't use QuickLatex or something like that. If they go down one day the answer is useless. What really should be done is to make them reconsider MathJaX on StackOverflow.

Comment: Makes so much sense! Thank you!!

Comment: @Royi that wasn't why I suggested using quicklatex. I wanted Ash to DOWNLOAD the images and embed them into his answer. You cannot directly link to QuickLatex anymore as the images are not secure with https. However, I agree with MathJax completely.